# Understanding the double star notation in Python in an algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am confused about the following code in Python:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand, randn

def generate_data (beta, n):
       u= np.random.rand(n,1)
       y= (u**np.arange(0,4))@beta
       return y
    
np.random.seed(12)
beta = np.array([[10,-140,400,-250]]).T
n = 5 
y = generate_data(beta, n)
print(y)
```

I really do not understand the meaning of
`u**np.arange(0,4)`, especially since `u` is a vector of dimension n times 1 (where n is arbitrary) and `np.arange(0,4)` is a vector of dimension 1 times 4. Nonetheless, this algorithm **works**.

I therefore tried the following:

```
import numpy as np

u= np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]).T
beta = np.array([[10,-140,400,-250]]).T
y = (u ** np.arange(0,4)) @ beta

print (y)
```

This time `n` is set to be 6. However, this algorithm **does not work** and there is an error message about the dimensions.

Can anyone please tell me about the meaning of the mysterious `u ** np.arange(0,4)`?

Comment: In this case `**` means to the power of. In many other languages it would be `^`.

Comment: @Klaus D. Thanks. But how do we take the power of an array to an array? Why does the first algorithm work but not the second?

Comment: When a (n,1) array is use with a (m) array, the result is (n,m).  This is true for addition, multiplication as well as this power.  I'd suggest spending some time reading the numpy `quickstart`, paying attention to `broadcasting`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ** will do the power operation element wise. Here is some example code that will make it clear:

```
>>> a = np.array([2,3,4])
>>> b = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a**b
array([ 2,  9, 64], dtype=int32)
```

As you can see, the 0th element of a is raised to the power of the 0th element of b, the 1st element of a is raised to the power of the 1st element of b, and so on.

EDIT:

My original answer didn't address part of your question. Here's an example to show why it worked with an arbitrary value of n.

Let `a` be a numpy array with dimension `(6,1)`.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]])
>>> a.shape
(6, 1)
>>> b = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a**b
array([[  1,   1,   1],
       [  2,   4,   8],
       [  3,   9,  27],
       [  4,  16,  64],
       [  5,  25, 125],
       [  6,  36, 216]], dtype=int32)
```

Notice that the output array has dimension (6,3). 6 is the first dimension of `a`, and 3 is the first dimension of `b`. When there is a dimension mismatch, the operator raises each element of `a` to the power of each element to `b`.

The reason your test example didn't work is because of a little detail. In your second code block (the code to test the operator), `u` had a shape of `(6,)` instead of `(6,1)`. `(6,)` probably doesn't work due to a small incompatibility between numpy arrays and the python ** operator.

Comment: Thanks. But why does the first algorithm work? n can be set to be any number, like 5 in the example. This clearly does not match with the dimension of the other array...

Comment: I missed that part of the question, I edited my answer to explain that as well